# matplotlib boxplot with split y-axis

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, boxplot

I would like to make a box plot with data similar to this

```
d = {'Education': [1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,3,3,3,3,4,4,4,4], 
 'Hours absent': [3, 100,5,7,2,128,4,6,7,1,2,118,2,4,136,1,1]}
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d) 
df.head()
```

This works beautifully:

```
df.boxplot(column=['Hours absent'] , by=['Education'])
plt.ylim(0, 140)
plt.show()
```

But the outliers are far away, therefore I would like to split the y-axis.
But here the boxplot commands "column" and "by" are not accepted anymore. So instead of splitting the data by education, I only get one merged data point.
This is my code:

```
dfnew = df[['Hours absent', 'Education']] # In reality I take the different 
columns from a much bigger dataset

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)

ax1.boxplot(dfnew['Hours absent'])
ax1.set_ylim(40, 140)

ax2.boxplot(dfnew['Hours absent'])
ax2.set_ylim(0, 40)

ax1.spines['bottom'].set_visible(False)
ax2.spines['top'].set_visible(False)

ax1.xaxis.tick_top()
ax1.tick_params(labeltop='off')  # don't put tick labels at the top
ax2.xaxis.tick_bottom()

d = .015  # how big to make the diagonal lines in axes coordinates
# arguments to pass to plot, just so we don't keep repeating them
kwargs = dict(transform=ax1.transAxes, color='k', clip_on=False)
ax1.plot((-d, +d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)        # top-left diagonal
ax1.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (-d, +d), **kwargs)  # top-right diagonal

kwargs.update(transform=ax2.transAxes)  # switch to the bottom axes
ax2.plot((-d, +d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)  # bottom-left diagonal
ax2.plot((1 - d, 1 + d), (1 - d, 1 + d), **kwargs)  # bottom-right diagonal

plt.show()
```

These are the things I tried (I always changed this both for the first and second subplot) and the errors I got.

```
ax1.boxplot(dfnew['Hours absent'],dfnew['Education']) 
#The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), 
#a.any() or a.all().
ax1.boxplot(column=dfnew['Hours absent'], by=dfnew['Education'])#boxplot() 
#got an unexpected keyword argument 'column'
ax1.boxplot(dfnew['Hours absent'], by=dfnew['Education']) #boxplot() got an 
#unexpected keyword argument 'by'
```

I also tried to convert data into array for y axis and list for x axis:

```
data = df[['Hours absent']].as_matrix()
labels= list(df['Education'])

print(labels)
print(len(data))
print(len(labels))

print(type(data))
print(type(labels))
```

And I substituted in the plot command like this:

```
ax1.boxplot(x=data, labels=labels)
ax2.boxplot(x=data, labels=labels)
```

Now the error is ValueError: Dimensions of labels and X must be compatible.
But they are both 17 long, I don't understand what is going wrong here.

Comment: Dimensions of `x` are (17, 1), dimensions of `labels` are just (17,). Also do not throw random keyword arguments to a function, it seldom works, ten minutes looking at the docs can save you several hours of that. But if `DataFrame.boxplot` works for you why do you want to switch to `Axes.boxplot`?

Comment: @Goyo Sorry, I'm very new to python. I used the axes.boxplot instead of the df.boxplot, because the code for breaking the y-axis worked for that, but not for the df.boxplot. I see now, I should not have used the df.boxplot keywords on the axes.boxplots. Thanks for pointing this out! But x and labels are both part of thematplotlib.pyplot.boxplot and the axes.boxplot. When I tried to use data and labels as array, now both (17,1) it threw the same ValueError. Thanks a ton for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overcomplicating this, the code for breaking the Y-axis is independent of the code for plotting the boxplot. Nothing keeps you from using `df.boxplot`, it will add some labels and titles you do not want but that is easy to fix.

```
df.boxplot(column='Hours absent', by='Education', ax=ax1)
ax1.set_xlabel('')
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=90)

df.boxplot(column='Hours absent', by='Education', ax=ax2)
ax2.set_title('')
ax2.set_ylim(ymax=50)
fig.subplots_adjust(top=0.87)
```

[image: Pandas boxplot]

Of course you can also use matplotlib's boxplot, as long as you provide the parameters it needs. According to the docstring it will make

> a box and whisker plot for each column of `x` or each vector in
>   sequence `x`

Which means you have to do the "by" part yourself.

```
grouper = df.groupby('Education')['Hours absent']
x = [grouper.get_group(k) for k in grouper.groups]

ax1.boxplot(x)
ax1.set_ylim(ymin=90)

ax2.boxplot(x)
ax2.set_ylim(ymax=50)
```

[image: matplotlib boxplot]

Comment: Thank you so much! This is so clear and easy. But I could not figure it our myself looking at the documentation! Thanks again!

Comment: Actually it is not working. This is very similar to what I tried in the beginning, but I get an error for both your versions( name 'ax1' is not defined). What is wrong here? I have numpy, pandas and matlotlib loaded (%matplotlib inline). I use jupyter notebooks with python3.

Comment: The name `ax1` must be defined after `fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(2, 1, sharex=True)`. That is in already in your code.

Comment: Fantastic! This is not trivial for someone who is getting started. I really appreciate your patients with me! Thanks a ton!